# Convert JSONObject into JSONArray using Python

Tags: java, python, json

I have gone through various threads, but couldn't find the particular answer in python. 
I have a json file

```
{
    "StoreID" : "123",
    "Status" : 3,
    "data" : {
            "Response" : {
                    "section" : "25",
                    "elapsed" : 277.141,
                    "products" : {
                            "prd_1": {
                                    "price" : 11.99,
                                    "qty" : 10,
                                    "upc" : "0787493"
                            },
                            "prd_2": {
                                    "price" : 9.99,
                                    "qty" : 2,
                                    "upc" : "0763776"
                            },
                            "prd_3": {
                                    "price" : 29.99,
                                    "qty" : 8,
                                    "upc" : "9948755"
                            }
                    },
                    "type" : "Tagged"
            }
    }
}
```

I need to convert this json file into the format below, by changing json object 'products' into an array form.

```
{
    "StoreID" : "123",
    "Status" : 3,
    "data" : {
            "Response" : {
                    "section" : "25",
                    "elapsed" : 277.141,
                    "products" : [
                            {
                                    "price" : 11.99,
                                    "qty" : 10,
                                    "upc" : "0787493"
                            },
                            {
                                    "price" : 9.99,
                                    "qty" : 2,
                                    "upc" : "0763776"
                            },
                            {
                                    "price" : 29.99,
                                    "qty" : 8,
                                    "upc" : "9948755"
                            }
                    ],
                    "type" : "Tagged"
            }
    }
}
```

Is there any good way to do it in python. Mostly I saw people are using java, but not in python. Can you please let me know a way to do it in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the values() of products dictionary and that will give you an array of values. Code below works from me assuming your json is in file1.txt Also note

```
import json
with open('file1.txt') as jdata:
    data = json.load(jdata)
    d = data
d["data"]["Response"]["products"] = d["data"]["Response"]["products"].values()
print(json.dumps(d))
```

**output:**

```
{"Status": 3, "StoreID": "123", "data": {"type": "Tagged", "Response": {"section": "25", "products": [{"price": 9.99, "upc": "0763776", "qty": 2}, {"price": 29.99, "upc": "9948755", "qty": 8}, {"price": 11.99, "upc": "0787493", "qty": 10}], "elapsed": "277.141"}}}
```

Comment: He may want to sort the output by the keys (e.g., `[v for k, v in sorted(d["data"]["Response"]["products"].items())]`). But otherwise, yeah, this is all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks. This is working perfectly for me. Couldn't vote up, as I do not have the credibility.

Comment: @user2129946, thank you. You should be able to select it as answer and that will add up to your trust level(votes) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
import json
import copy

a = json.load(open("your_data.json", "r"))

b = copy.deepcopy(a)

t =  a.get('data').get('Response').get('products')
b['data']['Response']['products'] = t.values()    # Originally was: [t[i] for i in t]
```

You can give back JSON with `json.dumps(b)`

Comment: Why have you added the `deepcopy`? And why use a listcomp to do what `t.values()` already does? (Or `list(t.values())` in 3.x.)

Comment: @abarnert I used deepcopy just as a precaution, OP is free not to use it. The list comp is bad, Should have just done the t.values()

Comment: As a precaution against what? To avoid modifying a temporary object that he has no apparent use for? Or are you planning on iterating over (part of) `a` while changing `b` or something (in which case it might be necessary)?